Why compilers treat differently parenthesized type followed by an initializer list in C++?
Why the same code below compiles fine with CLang and doesn't compile with MSVC?
#include <iostream>

const char * NumberToText(int val)
{
    return (const char *[]) {
        "Zero",
        "One",
        "Two", 
    }[val];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << NumberToText(2);
}

Here is the demo.
And MSVC gives the error:

(5): error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax

At the same time CLang compiles and executes this just fine.
In the Error C4576 in VS2015 enterprise I see some ideas that this is because this is C language feature and this is ill-formed in C++, but why CLang compiles this, then?
Can I keep the array anonymous and still get the same result in MSVC C++?

The MSVC error message tells you why: It's a nonstandard extension in some compilers.

@interjay, thanks, I see. Are there any straightforward workarounds to get the same result with anonymous array?

gcc, clang, msvc all warn/error about this - live - https://godbolt.org/z/P4sWWxrrE If it compiles for you check you pass  Standard Conformance mode switche(s) to the compiler.

@DamirTenishev why exactly do you need an "anonymous" array? You can have a named static variable array in the function and return its elements instead

@TheDreamsWind, I do. My intention was to clean up the code a little bit (Occam's razor) removing unnecessary things (easier to read, easier to support). But in this case it seems simpler to have in untouched rather than improve in this way.

The syntax (T){E1, E2, ...}, where T is a type and E* are expressions, is not valid standard C++ syntax.
It is valid C though, where it is a so-called compound literal. Some compilers allow compound literals in C++ code when not compiling in a strict standard-compliance mode (e.g. -pedantic-errors), but it is not obvious how these compound literals behave in a C++ context.
In particular, in GCC (and probably Clang as well), compound literals have different semantics in C++ code than in C code. Their lifetime and value category are different. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html.
So, I suggest not using them, even if you only compile for compilers supporting them.
Your example can be easily rewritten in standard-conforming C++:
return std::array{
    "Zero",
    "One",
    "Two", 
}[val];

or pre-C++17:
return std::array<const char*, 3>{
    "Zero",
    "One",
    "Two", 
}[val];


Isn't the std::array that is used to return the const char* a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of this function, resulting in a dangling pointer?

@BasinhetVeld, const char* literals have program lifetime and std::array only stores their addresses, so despite the fact that std::array leaves scope/lifetime, the addresses it holds and returns are stay valid.

@DamirTenishev Thanks, I didn't realize that would happen here

@BasinhetVeld if that weren't the case, the original code would be invalid, too.
